# Does this snippet of C code compile?

Tags: c, while-loop

My teacher in C programming claimed that this is a correct declaration of a while loop in C.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while()
    {
        fork();
    }
}
```

According to him it is exactly the same as writing:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        fork();
    }
}
```

Will the 'while()' code compile in any of the C standards?

Comment: Both programs would be better written `int main(void)` (or at a pinch `int main()`) since neither uses either `argc` or `argv`.

Comment: What result did you get when you asked your compiler about it?

Comment: Here is what [IDEOne says about it](http://ideone.com/pabv4Z).

Comment: My teacher said it works with ANSI. I attempted to compile it with -ansi but got 'error: expected expression'.

Comment: What *exactly* did teacher say? Because no matter what valid expression you put, the loop will break anyway.

Comment: On a previous exam my teacher had a question that was: 
What does this snippet of code do:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while()
    {
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}

Many students answered, "it won't compile because while() is not a valid declaration" but he gave them all 0 points because according to him the loop would work and fork exponentially which would cause to program to crash.

Comment: So the answer is "generates compiler error".

Comment: @KlasSegeljakt It's time to get the grades back! Sad that your teacher didn't even bother to compile and check whether the code compiles.

Comment: I would be interested in teacher's opinion of the statement `if()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, your teacher is wrong.

`while` loop expects an *expression* as the condition. So you can't leave it blank.

This is slight different from a `for` loop though, where the condition can be empty:

```
for(;;) { 

}
```

C standard defines the syntax in *§6.8.5, 1  Iteration statements*

> while ( expression ) statement
>
> do statement while ( expression ) ;
>
> for ( expressionopt; expressionopt; expressionopt) statement
>
> for ( declaration;  expressionopt; expressionopt) statement

As you can see, the *expression* is *not* optional for a `while` loop. But it's optional for a `for` loop.

Comment: Do you think he should trade in his current teacher for a better one, like you could swap a bad text book for a better one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; I think he should argue with his teacher that he found some answer over the internet which proves that the expression of `while` can't be left as blank.

Answer (score 1):

`while()` code will not work. And you can see the reason when you try to compile the same. The error that you would get is as follows,

```
test1.c:7:11: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 while()
       ^
```

`while()` requires an expression inside its `()`.

Answer (score 1):

a loop needs a condition on when to execute. So no, your teacher may have been drunk

Answer (score 0):

The [C Standard, section 6.8.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5) says the syntax is `while (expression) statement`. The `expression` is not optional.

```
while ( expression ) statement
```

If your compiler accepts the first program, your compiler has a few extras which make it non-conformant: it is not a C compiler.